# What changes do I need to make in order to run clock at 1hz in digital clock using verilog, below is my code?

Tags: verilog

First module represents digital clock main module and next module is test bench.

1. If I want to operate at 50 or 100mhz what should I change?
2. How to change time scale in xilinx or vivado from ps/ns to sec or ms?

```
module digital_clock(clk,rst,en,sec,min,hours,days,months);

input clk,rst,en;
output reg[5:0]sec;
output reg[5:0]min;
output reg[4:0]hours;
output reg[4:0]days;
output reg[3:0]months;

reg[31:0]count=0;

always@(posedge clk)
begin
    if(rst)
        begin
            count<=0;
            sec<=0;
            min<=0;
            hours<=0;
            days<=0;
            months<=0;
        end
    else
        begin
            if(en)
                begin
                    count<=count+1;
                        if(count==???)   // what value should i keep??
                            begin
                                sec<=sec+1;
                                count<=0;
                            end
                        else
                            count<=count+1;
                        
                        if(sec==6'd60)
                        begin
                            min<=min+1;
                            sec<=0;
                        end
                        
                        if(min==6'd60)
                        begin
                            hours<=hours+1;
                            min<=0;
                        end
                        
                        if(hours==5'd24)
                        begin
                            days<=days+1;
                            hours<=0;
                        end
                        
                        if(days==5'd31)
                        begin
                            months<=months+1;
                            days<=1;
                        end
                        
                        if(months==4'd12)
                        begin
                            months<=1;
                        end
                   end
               end
            end 

endmodule

module digital_clock_tb();

reg clk,rst,en;
wire [5:0]sec;
wire [5:0]min;
wire [4:0]hours;
wire [4:0]days;
wire [3:0]months;

digital_clock d1(clk,rst,en,sec,min,hours,days,months);

initial clk=0;
always #5 clk=~clk;  //is it right? for 1hz

initial begin
#10 rst=1;en=0;
#20 rst=0;
#20 en=1;


#1000 $finish;
end

endmodule
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Verilog Testbench Clock](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24924956/verilog-testbench-clock)

Answer (score -1):

What you need to do is add and modify your verilog timescale to control how long the delay is. The compiler won't know what #10 means unless you define a time scale. I will post an example below of a timescale of 10ns/1ns, this will be a 100 Mhz clock, you can use a clock divider if you would like to run a 50 Mhz, or you could just change your delay to, `always #2 clk=~clk;`
You can use this as a starting place. Just modify that value for the frequency you are trying to simulate. Just a warning, delays are non-synthesizable. So it would be better to practice using a clock divider for controlling your clock frequency.

```
`timescale 10ns/1ns
module digital_clock(clk,rst,en,sec,min,hours,days,months);

input clk,rst,en;
output reg[5:0]sec;
output reg[5:0]min;
output reg[4:0]hours;
output reg[4:0]days;
output reg[3:0]months;

reg[31:0]count=0;

always@(posedge clk)
begin
    if(rst)
        begin
            count<=0;
            sec<=0;
            min<=0;
            hours<=0;
            days<=0;
            months<=0;
        end
    else
        begin
            if(en)
                begin
                    count<=count+1;
                        if(count==32'd0)   // what value should i keep??
                            begin
                                sec<=sec+1;
                                count<=0;
                            end
                        else
                            count<=count+1;
                        
                        if(sec==6'd60)
                        begin
                            min<=min+1;
                            sec<=0;
                        end
                        
                        if(min==6'd60)
                        begin
                            hours<=hours+1;
                            min<=0;
                        end
                        
                        if(hours==5'd24)
                        begin
                            days<=days+1;
                            hours<=0;
                        end
                        
                        if(days==5'd31)
                        begin
                            months<=months+1;
                            days<=1;
                        end
                        
                        if(months==4'd12)
                        begin
                            months<=1;
                        end
                   end
               end
            end 

endmodule

module digital_clock_tb();

reg clk,rst,en;
wire [5:0]sec;
wire [5:0]min;
wire [4:0]hours;
wire [4:0]days;
wire [3:0]months;

digital_clock d1(clk,rst,en,sec,min,hours,days,months);

initial clk=0;
always #100000000 clk=~clk;  //Updated for 1 Hz based off a 100 MHz clock

initial begin
#10 rst=1;en=0;
#20 rst=0;
#20 en=1;


#1000 $finish;
end

endmodule
```

If you would prefer to change your timescale unit, do the following.

```
`timescale <time_unit>/<time_precision>
```

so i.e.

```
`timescale 10s/1s
`timescale 1ps/1ns
`timescape 10ms/100ns
```

Comment: Sir the changes you made I have tried simulating but it not passing behaviour syntax and not even simulating.                                      Sir, one thing I am not understanding you have kept 100mhz clock but whereas it getting stopped at 1000ns how it will generate, it should be greater than 100mhz right?

Comment: Seconds should increment when counter reaches posedge clk that means 50mhz right half cycle?